# Mouse_move event is fired but updateChart function inside of it is called only once. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, mousemove

I have issue with windows form. Working on mouse move event which gets fired when mouse moves over chart and attempts to scroll the chart. When user click on chart it will call mouseDown event and grab point clicked. I am using this clicked point along with e.X(current point when mouse moves) in mouse move event to check if mouse is moving right or left. I can see change in values when mouse moves but that change is applied only once. i.e. When mouse is moved chart should scroll along with mouse. but all I get is just one shift in chart when I lift the mouse up. It does not scroll when mouse is moving instead it changes value when mouse mouse moves up.
Following is the code for mouse move and mouse up event.
Variable that I declared to use in following functions

```
 bool isMousepressed = false; //used to relate mouse event with zoom buttons
    bool isZoomed = false; 
    bool isMoving = false; //allow scrolling of chart after zooming in
    bool isMouseDown = false; //used to relate mouse events occured in zoomed in chart
    int pointClicked;
```

MouseDown

```
private void chart_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;

        //if mouse is clicked after first zoom in it will scroll chart
        if (isZoomed)
        { 
            this.Cursor = csrHand;
            pointClicked = e.X;
            isMoving = true;
            return;
        }

        //******when left click is made and we have some points in beginSelection 
        //******i.e. start point for zoom, then only you show the rectangle selection frame
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left && !isMousepressed)
        {
           //do something                
            isMousepressed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //do something      
        }  
    }
```

Mouse up event

```
private void chart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isMouseDown) return;

        //checking for zoom
        if (isZoomed && isMoving)
        {
            double offset = 0;
            //checks if mouse moved to left side after clicking --> scroll chart from right to left --> adding points at the end of chart
            if (e.X < pointClicked)
            {
                double xmax = lastmaxT;
                xmax = xmax + (0.20 * xmax);
                offset = xmax - lastmaxT;
                if (!isMouseEventOccured) { xStart = lastminT; }

                //after increasing value of xmax if it exceeds max x value then s  
                if (xmax >= maxNumChartPointZoomOut) { isMoving = false; return; }
                updateChart(lastSelectedProfile, lastSelectedWeldIndex, (xStart + offset), xmax);

            }
            //checks if mouse moved to right side after clicking --> scroll chart from left to right --> adding points at the beginning
            if (e.X > pointClicked)
            {
                //lastminT is xStart value after zoom in
                double xmin = lastminT;
                xmin = xmin - (0.20 * xmin);
                offset = lastminT - lastminT;
                if (!isMouseEventOccured) { xEnd = chartA.BottomMax; }

                //if after decreasing value of 
                if (xmin <= 0) { isMoving = false; return; }
                updateChart(lastSelectedProfile, lastSelectedWeldIndex, xmin, (xEnd - offset));
            }   
            return;
        }
        //checks if left mouse button is clicked or not to capture beginning point and then end point for drawing selection rectangle
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left && beginSelectionPoint != Point.Empty)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
```

here is the code for mouse up event

```
private void chart_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isZoomed)
        {
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            isMouseDown = false;
            return;
        }

        Point p1, p2;
        //when mouse up occurs it first checks, with isMousePressed, if mouse was pressed or not
        if (isMousepressed)
        {
            isMousepressed = false;
            isMouseEventOccured = true;
            isMouseDown = false;

            //do something... here I get the value of xStart and xEnd

            if (!isZoomed) { isZoomed = true; }

            //call updatechart() with start and end points on graph being p1/p2 or beginselection/endselection
            updateChart(lastSelectedProfile, lastSelectedWeldIndex, xStart, xEnd);

            lastminT = xStart;
            lastmaxT = xEnd;

            beginSelectionPoint = endSelectionPoint = Point.Empty;
        }
        else return;   
    }
```

As per my search and understanding mouse move event fires when mouse is moved over given control and executes code continuously (including calling of any function like I have updateChart()). Any explanation about mouse move event is appreciated if my understanding sounds wrong from mouse move event.

Note: my chart is not using MSChart and no DataVisualization package. I am new to development so I will try to provide as much info as I can to solve and any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You run `if(isMousePressed)` and then you set `isMousepressed = false;`. Next time it runs past this code it would seem the  `if` condition is not met.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I am setting    isMousePressed in mouse down event only when it is not zoomed. This flag is just to ensure that code in mouse up event runs and draws selection rectangle only when mouse is pressed and chart is not in zoomed.

Comment: `if (xmax >= maxNumChartPointZoomOut) { isMoving = false; return; }` I think, and im just speculating, that your `xmax` is now bigger then your `maxNumChartPointZoomOut`. This might be due to you updating your `lastmaxT` to a higher value in your Updatechart method.

Comment: I understand that as mousemove() is called repetitively xmax changes. if my `if(xmax >= maxNumChartPointZoomOut)` is true then it will return and will not execute updateChart even once and I am getting one time movement of chart